# PHP/MYSQL query execution time optimisation

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a great deal of difficulty with this set of queries. I cannot find a way to speed up the second query at all. I've tried joining the the first query as a subquery on the second one, running through the first query results one by one and the current setup, all of which have proven extremely slow.

I would like to simply add a limit to the second query instead of this hocky stuff but our mysql version is too old to support it. For some reason it is also treating `EXPLAIN`as a syntax error, which is unhelpful.

How can I reduce the execution time of this?

```
$limitQuery = $pdo->prepare("
            SELECT r.supplier_option_code FROM third_party_raw_stock_price AS r ORDER BY r.id LIMIT 100
        ");
        $limitQuery->execute();
        $limitIds = $limitQuery->fetchAll();
        $limitIds = implode("', '",array_column($limitIds, 'supplier_option_code'));
        $limitQuery = null;
        $linkColumn = 'supplier_code';
        $thirdPartyId = 'FS';


        $migrateQuery = $pdo->prepare("
            UPDATE third_party_raw_stock_price AS r
  JOIN options_new AS o
    ON o.".$linkColumn." = r.supplier_option_code AND r.supplier_prefix = '".$thirdPartyId."'
  JOIN third_party_config AS t
    ON t.code = '".$thirdPartyId.""'
SET o.price = '989.99', o.cost_price_variation = '3.33', o.stock = '7'
WHERE r.supplier_option_code IN ('$limitIds')
        ");
    $migrateQuery->execute([':config' => $thirdPartyId]);
```

Comment: `EXPLAIN` works not with `UPDATE` and mostly important are the right indexes in the database tables. recreate your second query as select only and then use `EXPLAIN` to check the keys

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions it depends on the version of MySQL. In the more recent versions, explain does support the update statement.

Comment: @Shadow He notes that he has an old MYSQL version. But my last comment, was a little unclear on that. :)

Comment: Pretty much what @JustOnUnderMillions said: rewrite your UPDATE into a SELECT and do an EXPLAIN on it to see if you can improve it with indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Turns out the problem was that someone removed all the indexes from one of the tables on our dev enviroment!